# some variables is inaccessible during debug

Tags: eclipse, debugging

I am currently debugging custom library. 
Moving deeper and deeper in calls I get to the external class (not mine libraries like `jackson` for example) where the values of the variables is not being displayed and I cannot print them using `display` tab either.

How to make them accessible?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When compile, you can control how much debugging information should be generated into the class files.

```
Choice   Option                 Information generated in class
     1   -g:none                No debug information
     2   -g:lines               Line number only
     3   -g:lines,source        Line number & source file
     4   (default)              Same as #3
     5   -g:lines,source,vars   Line number, source file & variables
     6   -g                     Same as #5
```

I doubt that the class files in the library compiled without variables information. If you have source code, build it by yourself with appropriate option to include the debugging information, like `-g:lines,source,vars`.

Comment: Oh! I see. So those libraries it seems was compiled using `3` or `4`